# Group rows programatically in react-table v7

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I have an external filter for groupBy and on change of it's value I need to group rows according to that selected options.

I have options like Date, User, Name etc and need to group rows on basis of the selected option.
I went through the example provided for grouping though it is triggered when column is clicked, whereas I want the grouping to occur when that filter value changes.

Would appreciate the suggestions.

Have tried to groupBy programatically for column date. Though I get "**Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate**"

```
const columns = React.useMemo( () => [ { Header: "Date/Time", accessor: "date", Cell: row => { console.log("date",{row},row.column); if (watch("groupBy") === "Date" && !row.column.isGrouped) { row.column.toggleGroupBy(row.column.id, true); } return ( <span> {moment(row.value).format("DD/MM/YYYY - hh:mm A")} </span> ); } }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setGroupBy` method returned from `useTable`, here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-williamson-r05vk?file=/src/App.js:687-697)

Comment: Chen Dachao, yes I found it and implemented it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It seems 7.8.0 doesn't have setGroupBy anymore